# Python:: program to input a date and output how many days into the year it is

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone help me with this? A program in python that inputs a date and outputs how many days into the year it is. Example: may 5th is the 125th day of the year (do not consider leap year)

Comment: so someone types "may 5th"? or 5/5 ? or ??

Comment: `(datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 5) - datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1)).days + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from datetime import date

input_date = date(2012, 5, 5)

delta = input_date - date(input_date.year, 1, 1)
print delta.days
>>> 125
```

Or if you want to know how many days from today:

```
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.now().timetuple().tm_yday
>>> 249 # or 250 depending on where you are on the world at the moment
```

Comment: The first code you suggested shows and error. But all I want is for it to count the number of the day from the start of the year. Example: Jan 2nd input should give the output 2 as it is the 2nd day in the year.

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Can you please paste the error code? The only thing you have to change is 'date(2012, 5, 5)' to your desired date

What kind of input do you want to type in? 'Jan 1st', 'Jan 2nd', ... Note that date(2012, 5, 5) is in format date(YYYY, MM, DD)

Comment: the error it shows me is:: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    print delta.days
NameError: name 'delta' is not defined

Comment: I get the same Traceback in Python 2.6.6 when I comment/delete the `delta = input_date - date(input_date.year, 1, 1)` - line. So make sure that you copy the whole code and change nothing except of **date(2012, 5, 5)**
The code is working for me in Python 2.6.6

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring leap year issues, just add up the number of days in each month prior to the date from the beginning of the year (if any), then add the day of the month of the date requested. Alternatively you could Python's `datetime` module.